# Java: Is there any real performance cost for passing object references between looped methods

Tags: java, performance, game-loop

**Scenario 1:**

```
public class Game {
    public void doSomething(Hero hero, Enemy enemy){
        if (hero.IsAlive()){
            hero.checkCollisionWith(enemy);
        }
    }
}
```

**Scenario 2**

```
public class Game {
    Hero hero;
    Enemy enemy;

    public Game(Hero hero, Enemy enemy) {
        this.hero = hero;
        this.enemy = enemy;        
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        if (hero.IsAlive()){
            hero.checkCollisionWith(enemy);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, under normal circumstances, I guess either would be acceptable, however, in a game-loop that is going to be called 60 times per second, is the first option generally to be avoided?  How much of a performance hit is there for passing references through methods that are being called in a loop?

Bear in mind also that this is just an example, in the real project, there would be a *lot* more of these methods being called and a lot more objects involved.

Would it be wiser to give the game class the references it needs upfront (at construction) rather than constantly passing them about?

Comment: I think that difference is so small in comparison with actual `checkCollisionWith` logic, so you don't have to bother about it.

Comment: 60 times a second isn't all that much. I suggest you have more important performance concerns to worry about. It's more of a design question. Does the game really only have one Hero and one Enemy? If so, by all means have them as instance members. If not, not.

Comment: I removed pass-by-reference tag, Java is **always** pass-by-value.

Comment: Measure, measure and measure. But first of all, make sure you've written correct code that represents your world accurately. If the participants in a game cannot change during the game, that suggests passing them to the constructor of the game and storing them in `final` fields is appropriate. Not because it's faster but because it expresses better what a game is and how it works. But only you know what exactly you want to model.

Comment: @ChetanKinger, could you elaborate on why this question throws "all syntax rules of the java language out of the window"?  Thanks - just curious :-)

Comment: Thankis @EJP, indeed, although I *do* actually have only one enemy object and one hero object, I also have a multitude of other objects - although not necessarily ones that are required by the doSomething() method - the example given was simplified.  I do have another question in regarding alternatives to instance variables when dealing with lots of objects - thanks :-)

Comment: @Zippy Two users have been kind enough to edit your question and correct your mistakes. If you still don't get it, I doubt any explanation that I give will help. But since you are curious, here goes.. Before anyone edited your question, `public class game(){` and `public class game(Hero hero, EnemyGame enemy){` is not allowed in Java. This is throwing the syntax rules out of the window..

Comment: Oops, @ChetanKinger.  Of course I see the mistake now - I honestly didn't notice it when I wrote it.  I didn't copy the code from my project I just typed it.  Yep, the arguments of course were **only supposed** to be in the constructor, not the class declaration :-)

Comment: @Zippy That's okay. Mistakes happen. Most users who point them out are usually right ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parameter passing in this way is extremely efficient - the difference between calling a function without parameters and one with parameters is negligible.

Especially in the context of a game where the rendering/collisions/AI code is certainly going to be very processor intensive a small difference like this won't matter.

However from a simplicity and elegance of code point of view I think your second solution is more contained, more traditional OOP and readable.